# jQuery 1.4 change(), checkbox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a checkbox that is set to checked when the page is loaded. If/when the checkbox is unchecked I need to run a function. The following code works fine in all browsers with the exception of IE. In versions 7 and 8(haven't even tested 6) it works but you are required to uncheck it, check it, then on the second uncheck it executes the function. The jQuery documentation states: "As of jQuery 1.4 the change event now bubbles, and works identically to all other browsers, in Internet Explorer"... but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

The code:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Are you using 1.4.0, 1.4.1, or 1.4.2? The `change` event got some major love in 1.4.2

Comment: @Nick What sort of *love* did it get? :P

Comment: @alex - This commit was the big one: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/5267824aa36f0fcecb944a4daf0b99d6e01460fd but there are a half dozen others that went in to events for 1.4.2 as well: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/1.4.2/src/event.js

Comment: @Nick - I was using 1.4.1 simply changing to 1.4.2 did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @mike - Excellent :) I'll add this as an answer below so it helps the next guy/girl finding this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to jQuery **1.4.2**+ to resolve this.  The [1.4.2 release](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/) included [several changes/fixes for events](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/1.4.2/src/event.js).

This `change` event, `change` bubbling in IE (big one for many people), and lots more was fixed in that release, upgrading will resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop event bubbling, use

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(event) { 
    event.stopPropagation();
    // do something 
});
```

Perhaps you could also do something like

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $('#checkbox').click(function() { // assuming this will be fired for keyboard as well

        $(this).change();
    });

};
```

This *may* force the event.